# Send an array of files using the scp1 module to a remote server in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, scp

I've been trying to use npm's scp1 module to send files to a remote server of mine. And I've been able to use it for a single file, but I need to do that for multiple files. So the send function is a promise from what I can understand. I've tried using the async module but I haven't had much luck since I've only seen examples with callback functions as opposed to promises. Here's what I have so far

```
sendFile(file_path, file_name).then(function (response) {
                       //fs.unlinkSync(file_path)
                       console.log("sent file");
                   }).catch(function (error) {
                       console.log(error);
                   });
```

Every way I've tried so far only sends the first file when I try to do the same thing for an array of files. I just want to be able to use this same function to send multiple files from an array.

EDIT:

What I'm trying -

```
    var obj = [{'filename':f1, 'remotefile':splitTest(f1)}, {'filename':f2, 'remotefile':splitTest(f2)}, {'filename':f, 'remotefile':splitTest(f)}, {'filename':f3, 'remotefile':splitTest(f3)}];
  Promise.all(obj.map(({filename, remotefile}) => sendFile(filename, remotefile).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })))
```

I can now see an error that says - Error: write after end

So I guess its trying to execute all my functions in parallel?

Comment: `Promise.all(files.map(sendFile))`

Comment: Do I require promise by doing 'var Promise = require("bluebird");' ?

Comment: only if you have an OLD nodejs, or want bluebird's sugary goodness

Comment: Alright,E.g.
 so I've used require('promise') instead. I'm still new to this. So this is what my sendFile function looks like -    

function sendFile(localfile, remotefile) {
        return client.put(localfile, remotefile)
        
   }  

Basically it has two arguments, the first one is local file path and the second one is the remote file path which is basically the last part of the local file part 

I can split the local file path to get the remote file path, but my question is how do I pass the 2nd arg to this - Promise.all(files.map(sendFile))

Comment: `localAndRemoteFileNames.map(({localFile, remoteFile}) => sendFile(localFile, remoteFile))` then (or whatever fits your array data), but mapping to promises is the general idea

Comment: Okay I guess I’m doing it wrong, here’s what I have so far 

    var obj = [{'filename':f1, 'remotefile':splitTest(f1)}, {'filename':f2, 'remotefile':splitTest(f2)}, {'filename':f3, 'remotefile':splitTest(f3)}];

    Promise.all(obj.map(({filename, remotefile}) => sendFile(obj.filename, obj.remotefile)))

Not sure what I’m doing wrong

Comment: code is easier to read in the question

Comment: I've added an edit to my original question

Comment: Alright, so I corrected my syntax and ran it the way you suggested but, I have 3 files in my array and each time, only two files get sent over. And there's no order to it as well, it randomly pics the two files each time its run.